# Different returns when using task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have an application with an asynchronous method that has to return a List from List , the problem is that a conversion error occurs in return

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

The code is like this

```
private async Task<List<IWebElement>> Acessar(IWebDriver driver, string data)
    {

        var acessar = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            LoginNgin.Login(config.User, config.Password, driver);

            RelatoriosEstaticos.AbrirRelatoriosEstaticos(driver);

            RelatoriosEstaticos.AbrirDataAtual(driver, data);

            var links = ListArquivos.ListaLinksDownlaod(driver);

            m_ProgressBar.Invoke(new AtualizarProgressCallBack(AtualizarProgress),
            new object[] {links.Count()});

            return links;
        });

        return await Task.WhenAll(acessar) //Error here;

    }
```

the strangest thing is that if I return the direct method, without assigning a variable, the error does not occur. As below

```
        private async Task<List<IWebElement>> AcessarNgin(IWebDriver driver, string data)
    {

        var acessar = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            LoginNgin.Login(config.User, config.Password, driver);

            RelatoriosEstaticos.AbrirRelatoriosEstaticos(driver);

            RelatoriosEstaticos.AbrirDataAtual(driver, data);

            return ListArquivos.ListaLinksDownlaod(driver);

            m_ProgressBar.Invoke(new AtualizarProgressCallBack(AtualizarProgress),
            new object[] {links.Count()});

        });

        return await Task.WhenAll(acessar);

    }
```

Only I can not do this, because I need to give a .Count () to do something else.

Comment: Remove `Task.WhenAll` and do `await Task.Run(() => {....});` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: Task.Run solved my problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the `links` object you are returning is own its own a `List<T>` object. But the `Task.WhenAll` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx) expects a list of tasks or an enumerable and will return a list of the results of each call. I think, you du not have to use `Task.WhenAll(...)` at all, but rather `Task.Run(...)` as you only have one single task.